# UINavigationController Subclass navigationItem ignoring -setLeftBarButtonItem

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uinavigationitem

I currently have a subclass of UINavigationController that has the following viewDidLoad function.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIBarButtonItem *leftButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"HI" 
                                                                   style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                                  target:self
                                                                  action:@selector(manage)];
    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:leftButton];

    [self.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"top_nav_bg.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:3.0 topCapHeight:0.0] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

}
```

That UINavigationController subclass is one of the tabs in a UITabBarBarController subclass with the following viewDidLoad.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Change some of the look of the main tab bar
    [self.tabBar setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab_nav_bg.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:2.0 topCapHeight:0.0]];
    [self.tabBar setSelectionIndicatorImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab_nav_bg_active.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:2.0 topCapHeight:0.0]];

    // Load the various view controllers for this view
    SBHomeViewController *homeViewController = [[SBHomeViewController alloc] init];
    [homeViewController.tabBarItem setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab_home_active.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab_home.png"]];
    [homeViewController.tabBarItem setImageInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(5.0, 0.0, -5.0, 0.0)];

    // The navigation controller that will hold the home view
    SBMainNavigationViewController *homeNavController = [[SBMainNavigationViewController alloc] initWithRootViewController:homeViewController];

    self.viewControllers = @[homeNavController];
}
```

Everything is seemingly working fine. The correct navigation bar background imiage from the UINavigationController viewDidLoad is being loaded. However, the leftBarButtontem isn't being set at all. And for what it's worth, I tried making it the rightBarButtonItem, and that didn't work either.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The navigation controller is the container for other views and the host of the navigation bar. But, it is never part of the navigation stack. Only view controllers which are part of the stack have an effect on the bar button items.

Instead of setting the bar button item onto the navigation controllers navigation item, set it onto the root view controllers navigation item.

Comment: Good call. I had thought I tried that... Anyways, I moved the UITabBarController into the UINavigationController instead of vice versa as well because that made more sense.